# Get tiered price by customer group id

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group, tierprice

I'm writing a maintenance script to tidy up unused customer group tiered prices. How can I programatically get either: 
All products that have a tiered price for the selected customer group and then delete the tiered price for that group
OR 
Check if a product has a tiered price for the selected customer group and then delete the tiered price for that group.

Bear in mind I don't know the quantity, only the group id so I can't use getTierPrice() as that needs a quantity.

How do I delete the tiered price? Can I just use setTierPrice() and set the price and quantity to 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Current Customer Group Price, and Tier Price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147497/getting-current-customer-group-price-and-tier-price)

Answer (score 0):

```
$roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$TierPrice = $product->getData('tier_price');
$customer_grouptier = array_column($TierPrice, 'price','cust_group');
$customer_tier = $customer_grouptier[$roleId];
```

**$product** is the product Object.
More information click below.
[Getting Current Customer Group Price, and Tier Price](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147497/getting-current-customer-group-price-and-tier-price)

Answer (score -1):

Go to magento admin > product manager > edit a producct > price tab, add price according to customer group, then use the below code to display the price according to customer group ID but you need to loged-in first a customer to check the customer ID

```
$now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->timestamp( time() );
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customerGroup = 4; /* get logged-in customer group ID */

Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice( $now, $websiteId, $customerGroup, $_productId);
```

If you are in product listing OR detail page you can also use this code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

$groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price')

Enjoy! it will help you.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't seem to work.
If I echo:
   $price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice( $now, $websiteId, $customerGroup, $_productId); it doesn't return anything

Comment: you have added price as per group from admin?

Comment: Yes, the tiered prices have been added.

Comment: Not Tire prices, add "Group Price" and then check again

Comment: I'm not using group prices, I'm using tiered pricing.